# Clipboard content type Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Please help me to on this:

In word VBA i am trying to get the type of data copied in clip board.

how can i check the content type in clipboard using Word VBA.

Thank's

Comment: How are you currently accessing the clipboard contents? Please post a code example to help people understand your problem

Comment: This is old but may help you in some way http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-13999.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Getformat` method in `Clipboard Object`to check whether the clipboard has certain type of data... See these links for better clarifications...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebwdx8yh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240801(v=vs.60).aspx